# Annotating Groovy beans to load within Spring

Tags: spring, groovy

Our application uses `@Bean` to define create beans and load them into the Spring context.
We now need to externalize these, so as to enable the application to be configured without touching the java source code.

We wish to replace the `@Bean`'s with Groovy classes.

Is there a way to annotate a Groovy bean so that it will be picked up by Spring?

Note that we cannot simply reference each Groovy bean in the Spring XML, as we need to add and modify beans without touching the Spring code.

Thanks very much.

Comment: This sounds ominous to me. What goal do you want to achieve with this? Why is it so bad to change the "Spring code"? What does that even mean "Spring code"? The XML config? The `@Bean` annotations?

Comment: We handle process flows. The configuration for each process is defined as a separate instance of a base ProcessDefinition class. @Bean is used to define the different process instances, which extend ProcessDefinition. The goal is to avoid changing the source code (i.e. the java Bean configuration) everytime we add or edit  process configuration. The idea is to define instances of ProcessDefinition beans as Groovy classes which will be picked up by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring config inheritance.

Move all shared code in a common "base" project that each individual / specific project depends on. Use Maven for this.

Create a common / base Spring config and put that into the "base" project. This config doesn't contain a definition for `ProcessDefinition`

In the specific project, create one bean which inherits from `ProcessDefinition`. Create a Spring config which imports the base config and define the single specific bean in it.

Comment: Thanks, will do that. The existing system which this prototype may replace uses XML for configuration, however (for various reasons) it is is no where near as powerful as using a true object model defined in Java. The reason I was thinking of Groovy is because some others in the team do not think we should be changing Java 'source code' when configuration changes. My point is that this is not really source code. Perhaps you have a better way to express this or other points I could make. Again, thank you for your help.